# Issue with date funciton in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, store, strtotime

I have one issue with date function below i have put my all code. Please check. I have used jQuery calender in my joomla component

```
 echo $data['startpublish'];

    $data['startpublish'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['startpublish']));
    echo "?>>>>>>>>>>>".$data['startpublish'];

    exit;
```

I have store my date into mm-dd-yy format. When i store 01-02-2015 then it will store data in DB in (Y-m-d) format and when i store 01-28-2015 (28 Janvary)  then it will convert into 1970-01-01.

Please let me know what the issue . I have added both screenshot as well.

issue SS : http://prntscr.com/812w0c

correct SS : http://prntscr.com/812xbj

Comment: I think it is an issue with the 'strtotime' function, and not with the date function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `strtotime` quirk to do with the text date representation and the American illogical way of saying/writing dates used in the conversion having either `-` or `/` or `.` seperators.

[Quote from the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), now why did I go there for information I wonder.

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

So to make an american date format `01-28-2015` store properly you have to convert it to have `/` seperators like so for example

```
$data['startpublish'] = str_replace('-','/', $data['startpublish']);

$data['startpublish'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['startpublish']));
echo "?>>>>>>>>>>>".$data['startpublish'];
```